# What characters could a uuid_t created by uuid_generate contain?

Tags: c, uuid

The manual pages do not specify which characters a uuid_t could contain after passing it into uuid_generate. I need to know which characters, if any, are "off limits" to it because I am sending these through the network. If, for example, a uuid_t could contain '\0' or '\4' characters, I will have problems because my program treats those as "end of message" characters.

Comment: Where/how is *your* "uuid_t" defined? I would imagine it's to be treated as an *opaque struct/sequence of bytes* (representing all 128 bits of the UUID), and if so, then "all values of octects" are allowed (think of an `int` or `long`, for instance).

Comment: `uuid_t` can contain any bytes whatsoever. In theory, you could probably scan the generated value for your off limit "characters" and alter them (in as random a manner as possible).

Comment: Suggestion: Use [uuid_unparse](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_unparse) to convert it to a string before sending it over the network, then use uuid_parse to convert it back to a uuid_t.  You can convert the string to a more compact representation first if needed.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If ooga is correct, uuid_t by itself is not string-friendly, so I should definitely parse/unparse. Thanks. I suppose ooga answered my question, and you made my question irrelevant ;)